# How to handle Fortran global allocatable variables in a module across subroutines

Tags: module, fortran, global-variables, allocatable-array

I have the following module with an allocatable variable which is defined in the module, allocated in a subroutine, and then also used in a second subroutine called by the first subroutine. In this situation do I have to pass the variable to the second subroutine and declare `INTENT(inout)`? Or since it's a global variable it doesn't need to be passed as an argument?

```
MODULE test

  IMPLICIT NONE
  SAVE

  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:,:,:) :: total

CONTAINS

  !--- 1st subroutine
  SUBROUTINE my_subr1(n,m,z)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER,INTENT(in) :: n,m,z
    ALLOCATE(total (n,m,z))
    total=.9
    CALL my_subr2(n)

  END SUBROUTINE my_subr1

  !-- 2nd subroutine
  SUBROUTINE my_subr2(n)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER,INTENT(in) :: n

    total(n,:,:)=total(n-1,:,:)
  END SUBROUTINE my_subr2
END MODULE test
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: All subroutine within the module have access to `total`. Module variables are "save" by default, also. Your code hass issues though (no declaration of dummy arguments in `my_subr1` and no `end module ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do I have to pass the variable to the second subroutine and declare `INTENT(inout)`?

No, you don't. Any variable decalred in the body of the module has the `save` attribute by default. You must, though, ensure that the second subroutine is only called after the first was executed, or else the program will fail because `total` would not be initialized yet.

All functions and subroutines declared in the module will have access to `total` by host association.

---

By the way, there are some issues you should address in your code, as mentioned by @PierredeBuyl in the comments:

- Variables declared in the module body are saved by default; you should remove the `SAVE` statement.
- Procedures declared in a module inherit the `IMPLICIT` directive from the module scope, there is no need to redeclare it in the subroutine if you won't change it.
- You are missing the declaration of the arguments in `my_subr1`.

Comment: The `save` attribute isn't terribly relevant here.  Even under Fortran standards where there isn't that attribute by default, the call from `my_subr1` to `my_subr2` means the variable doesn't go out of scope between the two.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I have read about SAVE and IMPLICIT